# Does the preparedStatement avoid SQL injection?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have read and tried to inject vulnerable sql queries to my application. It is not safe enough. I am simply using the Statement Connection for database validations and other insertion operations.

Is the preparedStatements safe? and moreover will there be any problem with this statement too?

Comment: Prepared statements are the way to go. AFAIK a prepared statement would only be parsed once so there's no chance of SQL injection at a later date. Of course, you'll still need to sanitse input to protect against XSS attacks, etc.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Using string concatenation for constructing your query from arbitrary input will not make `PreparedStatement` safe. Take a look at this example:

```
preparedStatement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '" + userName + "';";
```

If somebody puts

```
' or '1'='1
```

as `userName`, your `PreparedStatement` will be vulnerable to SQL injection, since that query will be executed on database as

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '' OR '1'='1';
```

So, if you use

```
preparedStatement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
preparedStatement.setString(1, userName);
```

you will be safe.

Some of this code taken from [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Does the setString make any difference? what it actually does? Even thats going to substitute the string inplace. What different it makes?

Comment: @Mohamed: it makes a difference. The query `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?"` will be sent to the database where it's compiled and then `userName` from `setString` will be substituted. If the database sees an illegal value, it will throw an error. So, `' or '1'='1` will be treated as a whole string, and not as a statement involving operators `or` and `=`. The database will see it as a string with value `"' or '1'='1"`.

Answer (score 2):

The prepared statement, if used properly, does protect against SQL injection. But please post a code example to your question, so we can see if you are using it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well simply using `PreparedStatement` doesn't make you safe. You have to use parameters in your `SQL` query which is possible with `PreparedStatement`. Look [here](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=2301) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The [`PreparedStatement`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/) alone does not help you if you are still concatenating Strings.

For instance, one rogue attacker can still do the following:

- call a sleep function so that all your database connections will be busy, therefore making your application unavailable
- extracting sensitive data from the DB
- [bypassing the user authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

And it's not just SQL that can b affected. Even JPQL can be compromised if you are not using bind parameters.

Bottom line, you should never use string concatenation when building SQL statements. Use a dedicated API for that purpose:

- [JPA Criteria API](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-always-check-criteria-api-sql-queries/)
- [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/)