# String format ( or similar function ) or PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a difference and what is better practice to use: `String.format()` and manually insert values or `PreparedStatement` and parse values to placeholders (what is more size of code)?

Comment: As a side note, you seeking for "better practice" ... but asking "what is more size of code". You should realize that _quality_ is not the same as _quantity_.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, never ever use *plain string formatting* where `PreparedStatement` could be used. That latter has knowledge of your database SQL syntax. And will takes care of "shielding" every *special characters* much better than you.

Failure to follow that rule will result in high risks of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in your code.

See [Does the preparedStatement avoid SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333015/does-the-preparedstatement-avoid-sql-injection)

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental difference: a `PreparedStatement` will make whatever it takes so that the values you feed to it (via the `.set*()` methods) come as "neutral" to the database (or, rather, the "JDBC engine").

Note that `PreparedStatement` is an *interface*. As such, when using a JDBC driver for this or that database engine, it will be able to act differently depending upon said engine.

Do not use `String.format()` for that. Its role is quite different! `String.format()` cannot prevent SQL injection attacks; `PreparedStatement` can, unless its implementor did a really, *really* bad job.