# Searching between 2 date

Tags: java, sql

Have a problem search between 2 date 
my sql statement in java

```
String sql ="Select * from Payment where Payment_Date between '"+date_1+"' and '"+date_2+"'";
```

It give me data type mismatch， I guess my problem occur in '"+date_1+"' and '"+date_2+"' ??

date_1 and date_2 I get from

```
Date date_1 = date1.getDate();
Date date_2 = date2.getDate();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string should fix your issue.

Comment: what is your Payment_Date data type in database? date? string?

Comment: @kayla my data type in database is date

Comment: can you print your 'sql' ? i want to see completed query statement, so i could find what exactly the problem is

Comment: erm, what you mean print my 'sql'?

Answer (score 2):

Start using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) , it will prevent [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) . Read [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333015/does-the-preparedstatement-avoid-sql-injection) for more.

You can do something like this :

```
String sql ="Select * from Payment where Payment_Date between ? and ? ";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setDate(1, date_1 );
pstmt.setDate(2, date_2 );
// date_1 and date_2 objects should be of type java.sql.Date
```

Make sure you set the correct parameter types in the `setXXX()` methods. Remember if the data type for `Payment_Date` is `DATE` and related types, you need to set [**java.sql.Date**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) in the [setDate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,java.sql.Date)) method. If the data type of column is `TIMESTAMP`, then use [**java.sql.Timestamp**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and [setTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,java.sql.Timestamp)) method.

**Footnote :-**

If you have a `java.util.Date` object with you , you can convert that to `java.sql.Date` as :

```
java.sql.Date sqlDateObject = new java.sql.Date(utilDateObject.getTime());
```

Comment: java.sql.Date date_1 = (java.sql.Date) date1.getDate();
 java.sql.Date date_2 = (java.sql.Date) date2.getDate();
 Because what I doing is I get the date from JdateChooser and just put it in sql and find the date that I need

Answer (score 0):

Package of Date class must be java.sql not java.util.

```
 pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from Payment where Payment_Date between ? and ?"); 
 pstmt.setDate(1, date_1);
 pstmt.setDate(2, date_2);
```