# how to get dates between dates that user inter

Tags: php, mysql

How to get all data between to dates `(from-dates & to_dates )` that user enter from a html form  like. When user enter date like, from (1\1\2019) to (30\1\2019)
I want check if that two date between date in MySQL table

I tried :

```
 $from = $_POST['from'];
 $end = $_POST['end '];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE  '" . $from . "'  between 
  from_date and to_date and '" . $end . "'  between from_date and 
  to_date
  ";
```

from_date and to_date...col in mysql table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching between 2 date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670934/searching-between-2-date)

Comment: not exact query used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, but you should [format](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) `$from` and `$end` to correct format

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (date_column_name BETWEEN '" . $from . "' AND '" . $end . "') AND (date_column_name2 BETWEEN '" . $from . "' AND '" . $end . "')"
```

Where **table_name** is table you want to SELECT and **date_column_name** is your date column.

Comment: the user inter two date not one ...i want to check the two date that user inter

Comment: i have two date_column_name (from and to ) that i want to check

Comment: @HeshamMohmed Just add one more check, it's edit, check it and replace with your column names

Comment: thanks it works .... i try it before and doesn't work but now work fine may i wright syntax wrong ....again thank u :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    $from = $_POST['from'];
 $end = $_POST['end '];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE date_column1 >= '" . $from . "' AND date_column2 <= '" . $end . "' ";
```

Comment: @Hesham Mohmed let me know your progress

Comment: i have two date_column_name (from and to ) that i want to check from user post

Comment: @Hesham Mohmed now have a try

Answer (score 1):

> First you need to convert the input dates in to database date format
>   yyyy-mm-dd

```
 $from = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['from']));
 $end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['end ']));

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE  (date_column_name1 BETWEEN '" . $from . "' AND '" . $end . "')  AND (date_column_name2 BETWEEN '" . $from . "' AND '" . $end . "')";
```

OR

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE  (from_date_column >='" . $from . "' AND to_date_column <='" . $end . "')";
```

Comment: the user inter two date not one ...i want to check the two date that user inter   ..i convert the input date right

Comment: i have two date_column_name (from and to ) that i want to check

Comment: @HeshamMohmed I Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE  from_date >='$from' AND to_date <='$end';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE from_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$end' or to_date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$end';
```