# How to retrieve values from SQL when ID is in array form

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arrays, oracle

The function below will pick the highest value and it will display value which are in column place1(in table placeseen) as output based on the ID.So far I only can get the highest value but not the value in place1. 
I don't know what's wrong with my coding because the output is always shows empty.

```
   private void pick_highest_value_here_and_display(ArrayList<Double> value) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double aa[]=value.stream().mapToDouble(v -> v.doubleValue()).toArray();
            double highest=aa[0+1];
            for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++)
            {
                if(aa[i]>highest){
                    highest=aa[i];
                    String sql ="Select* from placeseen where ID =aa[i]";
                    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                    Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                    PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) 
                    {  
                    String aaa;
                    aaa=rs.getString("place1");
                    System.out.println(aaa);
                    }
                    ps.close();
                    rs.close();
                    conn.close();
                }

            }

            System.out.println(highest);
        }
```

Comment: use try catch you have an sql error `select*` and also `a[i]` should be outside the double inverted commas

Comment: I have tried with your method but still can't get the aaa value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
// as you are using preparedStatement you can use ? and then set value for it to prevent sql injection
String sql = "Select * from placeseen where ID = ?";
DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
Connection conn = db.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setDouble(1, aa[i]);  // 1 represent first attribute represented by ?

System.out.println(ps); // this will print query in console

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Inside rs.next()");  // for debug purpose
    String aaa;
    aaa=rs.getString("place1");
    System.out.println(aaa);
}
// remaining code
```

Comment: Do one thing, just sysout your preparedStatement after setting values, you will get query and they try to execute in mysql directly. See my updated answer.

Comment: I still getting the same output..which is the highest value only

Comment: did you get the query in your console?

Comment: I get this "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@151376dc: Select Place1 from placeseen where ID = 0.9805806756909202"....I have changed * to Place1

Comment: did you try to execute it in mysql directly?

Comment: ya..I think i should use i instead of aa[i]..aa[i] gives me 0.9805806756909202 but [i] give me 1

Comment: what do you want to use `aa[i]` or only `i`? What is your requirement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84768/discussion-between-user5156075-and-naman-gala).

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
  String sql ="Select * from placeseen where ID =aa[i]";//aa[i] taking a value
```

use

```
  String sql ="Select place1 from placeseen where ID =?";
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setDouble(1, aa[i]);
```

passing `aa[i]` variable value .

[Avoid sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333015/does-the-preparedstatement-avoid-sql-injection)

Comment: is the given condition is true? @user5156075

Comment: The placeseen table has 5 column, which are ID, place1,place2,place3 and place4..I want display place1 only –