# How are we still vulnerable to sql injection even when using prepared statements with parameters?

Tags: java, mysql

I have come to know that prepared statements are not guarantee to prevent SQL injection.

How can SQL injection be done even using prepared statements?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333015/does-the-preparedstatement-avoid-sql-injection for a more detailed explanation. Simply said: If used correctly, prepared statements protect against SQL Injection.

Comment: Others have said prepared statement is necessary but not 100% sufficient.

Comment: Also note [this answer on Information Security SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/44893).

Comment: I am not asking how it can prevent it.

Comment: I am asking even still using prepared statement how it can be done

Comment: I have come to know it from one of the legend of stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo

Comment: Go and read the duplicate, the answer is there.

Comment: It is not explained in the question which you are sugesting.    http://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic

Comment: No, it is explained in the first answer. It is also explained in the answer to the question Norbert van Nobelen mentioned. Why are you ignoring those answers?

Comment: Thanks! for your response.                                                                                             Please don't force me to accept what I am not asking.

Comment: Still it is the answer (Read the link from @RealSkeptic which is the most extensive): Prepared statement architecture is safe (if used correctly), however software has bugs, so that can still mess everything up.