# Else not working in If statement when using specific query for SQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have to connect a database to my codes to check a pin code. I have managed to make it but I'm having some problem to make the else part of the if statement to work. I think its the query part which is causing the problem as when I change the if..else statement it works perfectly.

If there is any other way to write this query to get the same result please let me know

thank you

```java
public void getOperation() {


    {       
        Connection conn = null;
        String query = "SELECT pin FROM customerdetails WHERE pin='"+Pin+"'";
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb", "user","@1234@");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String password =  rs.getString("pin");
                if (Pin.equals(password)) {

                     PinCheck = "Pin OK";  
                } else 
                {
                    PinCheck = "Invalid Pin";
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) {

            }
            if (conn != null ) {
                //conn.close();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Having this

```
  String query = "SELECT pin FROM customerdetails WHERE pin='"+Pin+"'";

    while (rs.next()) {
        String password =  rs.getString("pin");
        if (Pin.equals(password)) {

             PinCheck = "Pin OK";  
        } else 
        {
            PinCheck = "Invalid Pin";
        }

    }
```

makes little sense, as you will always have equal `Pin` - because you are querying for it. Check for results count. 1== Pin matches, 0== pin invalid.

Comment: This query is vulnerable for sql injection see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333015/does-the-preparedstatement-avoid-sql-injection

Comment: Im not getting it, could you please give me an example how to implement this in my code?

Comment: You are literally querying "get pin where pin is equal to X" and then you are checking if that Pin is X - well obviously it is.